# SQL Server Replication Conflicts

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, database-replication

I am doing merge replication and everything has been running fine for 4 months now. But am not happy with seeing few conflicts even after looking at the conflicts viewer, it is always resolve itself. But sometimes the `OP_ID` column would jump from its key eg from 76  to 2000 range which is not good and I just want to see what I can do because that appear only in this table for all databases which 12 databases and 3 subscribers. Please see the common error displayed. I have logged the details also in the conflict viewer. I have used different PC and recreated my merge replication working perfectly, yet it gives this unreal conflicts but putting in strange numbers in `op_ID` column of the `Transferopetions_DX`. Any other way because am using SQL Server 2005. Any help! See the message:

> A row insert at 'EUDTABZ-P9.*2393' could not be propagated
>   to 'EULTABZ-2393'. This failure can be caused by a
>   constraint violation.  Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint
>   'PK*_TransferOperatio__0C50D423'. Cannot insert duplicate key in
>   object 'dbo.TransferOperationDX'.

Comment: What type is op_ID column? Is it IDENTITY?

Comment: Thanks Alex. It is IDENTITY!. The databases are designed by the manufacturers, but just to have solid data backup and availablity, we are doing replication.

Comment: In case of IDENTITY, SQL server creates ranges of key values for each subscription. See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms152543(v=sql.90).aspx

Comment: Can I adjust the ranges with this function as shown in the article u highlighted using sp_adjustpublisheridentityrange ? How should I use it?

Comment: I do not have such experience. But by description of the function, yes, you can.

Comment: I am not sure if it is good to use it at this moment because this can only be used when the ranges have been exchausted. Should i leave it and also about the conflicts that happened, should I leave it as it is because those reported conflicts are already resolved, and yet the SQL still report it in the conflict resolver.